# How can I do valid tests simplification of a many-parameter distribution by consecutive parameter restrictions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, maximum-likelihood, restrictions, generalized-method-of-moments

Suppose I have a data set that I believe is well-described as draws from a particular four- or five-parameter distribution, such as the Amaroso or the GB2. Some of those parameters can be made to disappear for certain parameter values, most often zero or one. In the case of interest to me, there are several 3- or 4-parameter distributions that can be produced by such restrictions, of sufficient interest to have been assigned their own names, and a larger number of 2- or 3-parameter distributions that can be produced by two such restrictions.

I wish to test whether these sub-distribution producing restrictions are accepted by the data. Although I have several different parameter estimators for each distribution, restricted and unrestricted, such as MLEs, GMM, and maximum entropy estimators (I have each of those for every distribution), I am not sure what a good statistic to test each restriction would be. Can I use one test for each restriction, or do I need a different test statistic for hypothesis testing under each method of parameter estimation? In addition, my inclination would be to test one restriction on the unrestricted distribution, and if that restriction is accepted, to test the second restriction under the restricted model. But I am unsure this is proper when the tests all use a single data set. I also wonder if the second test needs to be adjusted in some way to account for the sequential testing.